# WooCommerce checkout a specific product without adding it to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to do this trick in WooCommerce, please help me out;

Having two buttons on a product; One button for SHOP NOW, and the other button for ADD TO CART.

If a client clicks on a Shop Now, he will be redirected to the checkout page. If he clicks on the Add to cart, the product will be added to cart.

The trick is that if SHOP NOW is clicked, the product doesn't have to be added to cart(even if there might be some products in the cart),

In simple words, I want a client to be able to shop a single product, without adding that product to the cart. Can you help me out please??